# java if statement in array for loop

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

Alright so I need to add some additional functions to this array, which gives 10 random integers. It needs to be able to store the numbers that are less than 40 and print them along with the numbers that are less than the average. How do I do this with an if statement in a for loop? (Ignore the stuff that's cometted out.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random gen= new Random();
        int[] ages = new int[10];

        for(int i=0; i<ages.length; i++){ //adds stuff to arrays


            ages[i] = gen.nextInt(100); //Determines the maximum used in random number generation
            }

        for(int x=0; x<10; x++){//prints the array with the below statement

    System.out.println(ages[x]);
        }
    System.out.println("---------------");
    System.out.println(ages[9]);
    System.out.println(ages[8]);
    System.out.println(ages[7]);
    System.out.println(ages[6]);
    System.out.println(ages[5]);
    System.out.println(ages[4]);
    System.out.println(ages[3]);
    System.out.println(ages[2]);
    System.out.println(ages[1]);
    System.out.println(ages[0]);
    int value = (ages[0] + ages[1] + ages[2] + ages[3] + ages[4] + ages[5] + ages[6] + ages[7] + ages[8] + ages[9]);
    System.out.println("The combined value of the integers is " + value + ".");

    int average = (value / 10);
    System.out.println("The average value of the integers is " + average + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: "less than 40"... Then why did you do `nextInt(100)`??

Comment: The nextInt(100) is for picking the numbers generated.

Comment: But you say it needs to store numbers less than 40

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Yeah, I do. It generates number within 1 and 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that? (Sorry guys for code but i don't have a time to make it better):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random gen= new Random();
    int[] ages = new int[10];
    List<Integer> agesLesserThan40 = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> agesLesserThanAverage = new ArrayList();
    float value = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        ages[i] = gen.nextInt(100);
        value += ages[i];
    }

    for(int x=0; x<10; x++){
        if(ages[x] < value/10) agesLesserThanAverage.add(ages[x]);
        if(ages[x] < 40) agesLesserThan40.add(ages[x]);
    }

    System.out.println("ages:");
    for(int z=0; z<10; z++){System.out.print(ages[z] + ", ");}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Lesser than 40: ");
    for(int y=0; y<agesLesserThan40.size()-1; y++){System.out.print(agesLesserThan40.get(y) + ", ");}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Lesser than average: ");
    for(int y=0; y<agesLesserThanAverage.size()-1; y++){System.out.print(agesLesserThanAverage.get(y) + ", ");}
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("The average value of the integers is " + value / 10 + ".");
    System.out.println("The combined value of the integers is " + value + ".");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how `if (value >= 100000)` says anything is less than 40...

---

Here is probably how you could divide your array into above and under 40.

```
final int AGES_TO_GENERATE = 10;
final int AGE_LIMIT = 100;
final int AGE_DIVIDER = 40;

List<Integer> lesserAge = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> upperAge = new ArrayList<>();

Random gen = new Random();
double averageAge = 0.0;
for(int i=0; i<AGES_TO_GENERATE; i++){ 
    int age = gen.nextInt(AGE_LIMIT); 

    averageAge += age;

    if (age < AGE_DIVIDER) lesserAge.add(age);
    else upperAge.add(age);
}
averageAge /= AGES_TO_GENERATE;

System.out.println("Here are the values less than 40");
System.out.println(lesserAge);

if (upperAge.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("There are no values over 40");
}
```

If using Java 8, you can print values less than the average very simply

```
lesserAge
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x < averageAge)
    .sorted() // Assuming you want to sort
    .forEach(System.out::println);

upperAge
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x < averageAge)
    .sorted() // Assuming you want to sort
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Okay but how also make it record values that are less than the average as well?